# Communicating Data Received from Server to Browser in Application based on Vert.x

Tags: javascript, vertex, event-bus, vert.x

I am developing an application which will show data on browser received from server using Ver.x. So, I have the following modules:

**server.java:**

```
NetServer server = vertxx.createNetServer();

    server.connectHandler(new Handler<NetSocket>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(final NetSocket sock) {

            System.out.println("A client has connected");                

            while (true) {           
                //Sending Message to Client after each five seconds
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                socket.write("HELLO Server: I am Client: " + i);                    
            }                         
        }
    });
```

**client.js:**

```
var client = vertx.createNetClient();

client.connect(1234, 'localhost', function(err, sock) {

   sock.dataHandler(function(buffer) {
       //Here I received data sent from server. Now, I want to show this data on browser.
   });
});
```

So, I want to show data on browser received on client from server. What can be possibilities for this? How I can show this data on browser gradually as received on client from server? Will I have to use some third component like vertex event bus? I need to append it in some HTML file to show data. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

why you don't use websockets..also you can check the event bus bridge...which allows you send and receive data from a event bus from your browser (basically you use websocket like other eventBus)

```
http://vertx.io/core_manual_java.html#sockjs-eventbus-bridge

<script src="http://cdn.sockjs.org/sockjs-0.3.4.min.js"></script>
<script src='vertxbus.js'></script>

<script>

    var eb = new vertx.EventBus('http://localhost:8080/eventbus');

    eb.onopen = function() {

      eb.registerHandler('some-address', function(message) {

        console.log('received a message: ' + JSON.stringify(message);

      });

      eb.send('some-address', {name: 'tim', age: 587}); //--------2)

    }

</script>
```

here you have a bus in your server named 'some-addres' then you can send data directly from your browser 2)

and you can register a eventbus and send it data from your server...
this is pretty clear, only remember configure your bus correctly allowing or not which bus are visibles from the browser..

```
vertx.createSockJSServer(server).bridge(config, noPermitted, noPermitted);
```

Comment: sorry I forget add the url..here it is...http://vertx.io/core_manual_java.html#sockjs-eventbus-bridge